# Jquery AJAX / Animation Control Flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a hard time working out a design pattern in Jquery to control multiple AJAX and Animations.  I of course have the AJAX and Animations bound to some events like 'click' but I'm trying to keep the code modular with functions and adding wrapper methods ($.fn), but I don't know how to get code to run when a function or a wrapper method is **complete**.

EDIT: Ok, it's a bit challenging to add in some sample code.  So here's some pseudo-code:

```
clickEventFunction(){
    ajaxRequest();
    ajaxRequest2();
    ajaxRequest3();
    animationFunction();
}
```

after **all** ajax requests **complete** I want an animation to fire off.

Comment: Are you talking about callbacks? Perhaps you could supply some sample code of what you are attempting to add a little clarity to the question.

Comment: It's not AJAX, it's DHTML. AJAX is when you fetch data from the server using XMLHTTP. AJAX has nothing to do with animation.

Comment: No, I'm familiar with the difference between AJAX and DHTML.  As far as I am concerned animation and AJAX go hand in hand.

Comment: Josh - yes, I guess callbacks are one solution which I am using to some extent, but I was wondering if there were other options or methodologies that I may be overlooking.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you can use a callback after each AJAX request is completed. In the callback you can use a counter or such to keep track of which requests have completed - once they are all complete, just trigger your animation.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now...it seems like a good idea, but it doesn't seem very graceful.